# Random without duplicate using stream and questions about sort Java

Tags: java, random, lambda, java-stream

I am trying to get 8 random int using stream but the problem with the code below is that distinct() removes duplicate which will not give me 8 int if there was any duplicate.

Goal:

1.Get 8 random int (no duplicate)

2.Add to List

3.Sort the first 7 int.

I know Collections.sort(winlist.subList(0, 6)); works for sorting but im trying to see if it can be done with just stream.

```
    new Random()
            .ints (8, 0, 64)
            .distinct()
            .sorted()
            .forEach (Integer -> System.out.print (Integer + "\n"));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an endless stream and limit it *after* the distinct operation.

```
new Random().ints(0, 64).distinct().limit(8).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

This will print 8 random integers from the range [0,64) in sorted order.

To sort only the first 7 numbers, it would be easier to use a stream with 7 numbers and generate the 8th number traditionally. However, if you really want to have one stream with all 8 numbers in it, you can create one by concatenating two streams.

```
IntStream.concat(
  new Random().ints(0, 64).distinct().limit(7).sorted(),
  new Random().ints(0, 64)
).distinct().limit(8).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Oh okay didn't know it could be done with limit after distinct. Nice, thanks.

Comment: Okay i will take note, but what if i only want to sort the first 7 int excluding the last one

Comment: The second Stream (`new Random().ints(0, 64)`) responsible for the last `int` may produce an `int` which is already in the first Stream. Applying `distinct` on the whole concatenated Stream may result in 7  unique `ìnt`s. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @LuCio the second stream is endless. After the second distinct operation there are exactly 64 numbers in the combined stream (even though it doesn't exist at that point due to lazy evaluation, but that's not important). You can try it yourself by replacing 64 with 8 and running the code multiple times. As you will see, the result will always have exactly 8 distinct numbers. If you replace 64 with something < 8 then the program will run forever, because it would search for a distinct 8th number which will never be generated.

Comment: @Socowi Thx - this is what I was missing. `Stream.concat` _creates a lazily concatenated stream_ (JavaDoc). (+1)